# How to sort MonthName (varchar) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got stuck while sorting the month name in order by in below query. Actually here `Period` is alias which user can choose if he wants to see result in daily, weekly, monthly or yearly. Sorting is working for rest of cases except month. As it is taking Month as string only and if I try to convert it into month it is giving exception.

Please have a look and guide me.

It is begin return like:

```
April
August
December
```

Desired output:

```
January
February
March
April
December
```

Code:

```
Declare @Period char = 'M'
Declare @FinalDateId int = 20170101;

SELECT
    Period, SUM(CAST(TotalAmount AS bIGINT)) AS Value
FROM            
    (SELECT        
         CASE 
            WHEN @Period = 'D' 
               THEN CAST(d.DateName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'W' 
               THEN CAST(d.WeekOfYear AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN @Period = 'M' 
               THEN CAST(d.MonthName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
               THEN CAST(d.CalendarYear AS VARCHAR(50)) 
         END AS Period, 
         Tr.TotalAmount
     FROM 
         Revenue AS Tr 
     INNER JOIN  
         Dates AS d ON Tr.DateId = d.Id
     WHERE        
         (Tr.DateId BETWEEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @Period = 'D' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 30, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'W' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 364, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'M' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 365, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 3652, 112) END AND @FinalDateId) 
         ) AS TotalRevenue
GROUP BY 
    Period
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN @Period = 'M' 
          THEN CONVERT(month, Period) 
    END
```

Output is returning without sort:

```
Period     Value
--------------------
April         4750
August        4750
December    187250
February      4000
January      12500
```

Desired output after sorting the month:

```
Period      Value 
-----------------------
January     12500
February     4000
April        4750
August       4750
December   187250
```

Shared the sample data/Table at https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak02JpVbvOzehy0Hs2r8Rxh6mhSR

Comment: Thanks for concern.. added output data

Comment: Still waiting on sample data that produced the sample output, as well as the exception you are getting.  Schematic would be nice, too.

Comment: Thankyou @marc_s for formatting the question correctly.

Comment: I am trying to fetch data with schema from management studio..

Comment: Added sample data to produce the sample output..

Comment: Btw: Your dates table (good idea to use one) is a little weird. You are using an `INT` value looking like a date as ID. A **string** like "20170820" can be casted implicitly (*unseparated format*), but this int is - uhm - funny... As you are using this field to join, you ought to have this value in your working tables too. Why don't you use the date itself as a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess around with the **names** of a date's part!

Any approach to build a *full date* using the month's name and some date fragment in order to get the month's *number* will fail, if the executing system has got a different language. If you application might ever run in international environment, you must find a way to deal with it without hacks.

If the period is a real date somewhere, you might extract the year and month simply by using `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` and order by both of them. Both come back with a numeric index.

But the solution seems to be even simpler:

Obviously you are using a dates table (which is a very good thing!)

From your posted example I take, that its column `[MonthOfYear]` has got the numeric month index. And you've got the `FiscalYear` too. So include these columns to your query and use `ORDER BY FiscalYear,MonthOfYear`.

Comment: Hi Shungo.. its working for month no doubt.. but than it is not working if we select period for Y, W, or D.. it goes on toes because we group by Year and Month.. :(

Comment: @Subodh It should be easy to create (concatenate) a string criteria for each case...

Comment: Please elaborate your idea.. are you meaning something like this:- CASE Period 
--     WHEN 'January' THEN 1
--     WHEN 'February' THEN 2
--     WHEN 'March' THEN 3
--     WHEN 'April' THEN 4
--     WHEN 'May' THEN 5
--     WHEN 'June' THEN 6
--     WHEN 'July' THEN 7
--  WHEN 'August' THEN 8
--  WHEN 'September' THEN 9
--  WHEN 'October' THEN 10
--  WHEN 'November' THEN 11
--  WHEN 'December' THEN 12
--     END

Comment: @Subodh no, something like `CASE @Period WHEN 'D' THEN ... WHEN 'W' THEN ...`, just as it was. But you have to create an **alphanumerically sortable *string* value** (like dates in ISO8601). One idea might be, to add columns to your date table with permanent sort values (one column for each type of `@Period`)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot understand how your code works. "CONVERT(month, Period)" is not valid (at least in my sql server machine it says "mont is not a system datatype").

Besides that, I think the best solution is to have another field for ordering:

```
       CASE 
            WHEN @Period = 'D' 
               THEN DATEPART(DAY,d.id)
            WHEN @Period = 'W' 
               THEN DATEPART(WEEK,d.id)
            WHEN @Period = 'M' 
               THEN DATEPART(MONTH,d.id) 
            WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
               THEN DATEPART(YEAR,d.id) 
         END AS PeriodNumber
```

Comment: Yes that is the only problem it is not allowing to convert month.. let me try your way as well..

Comment: You will have to combine a date's `MONTH()` with its `YEAR`, as you probably want to get the *December 16* **before** the *January 17*. If I get this correctly out of the provided example, all needed information is there already int the date's table.

Comment: Getting this exception -- > Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.  As d.id is in format 20170101.. but if I change it to d.DateName than it is working.. But I feel Shnugo given better answer to this problem.. I would like to THANK YOU FOR YOUR SUPPORT froxon

Comment: @Subodh You cannot cast the `INT` value 20170101 to a date, but you can cast it after you've casted it to `VARCHAR(8)`. Still a strange approach...

Comment: I have again tried this approach and found it does not work if I have half data from 2016 and half from 2017.. as week number on december is 52..53 and again it starts from Januvary it will be 1,2..

Comment: @Subodh This is exactly the reason why you should not sort after a *part* of a date. Using a dynamically defined `ORDER BY` needs some hacks. Either create a string-based sort value (**including the year**) or use independant statements, one for each need.

Comment: Yes Shnugo, I have used above logic + Year added to it.. and now it is working perfrectly fine.. I am adding my working query in last as there is limit of characters here I can post.

Answer (score 1):

I place this as a second answer, as it is half of a joke:

Look into this table_

```
select * from sys.syslanguages
```

You might use a numbered *string-split-approach* to get the month's index to a given month's name. This allows you to deal with different cultures dynamically:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS MonthIndex
      ,B.m.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS MonthName
FROM sys.syslanguages AS l
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(months,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted) AS A
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') AS B(m)
WHERE l.name='us_english';
```

But my strong advise is: Don't do it this way :-D

```
Inx Name
------------
1   January
2   February
3   March
4   April
5   May
6   June
7   July
8   August
9   September
10  October
11  November
12  December
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used comments provided by @froxon and @Shnugo.. I am very thanks full to both of them who helped me a lot to reach for final answer..

```
Declare @Period char = 'M'
Declare @FinalDateId int = 20170101;

SELECT
    Period, SUM(CAST(TotalAmount AS bIGINT)) AS Value
FROM            
    (SELECT        
         CASE 
            WHEN @Period = 'D' 
               THEN CAST(d.DateName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'W' 
               THEN CAST(d.WeekOfYear AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN @Period = 'M' 
               THEN CAST(d.MonthName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
               THEN CAST(d.CalendarYear AS VARCHAR(50)) 
         END AS Period, 
         Tr.TotalAmount,
         d.CalendarYear,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Period = 'D' 
               THEN DATEPART(DAY,d.DateName)
            WHEN @Period = 'W' 
               THEN DATEPART(WEEK,d.DateName)
            WHEN @Period = 'M' 
               THEN DATEPART(MONTH,d.DateName) 
            WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
               THEN DATEPART(YEAR,d.DateName) 
         END AS PeriodNumber 
     FROM 
         Revenue AS Tr 
     INNER JOIN  
         Dates AS d ON Tr.DateId = d.Id
     WHERE        
         (Tr.DateId BETWEEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @Period = 'D' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 30, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'W' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 364, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'M' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 365, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 3652, 112) END AND @FinalDateId) 
         ) AS TotalRevenue
GROUP BY 
    Period,
    PeriodNumber,
    CalendarYear
Order by 
    CalendarYear,
    PeriodNumber
```

Comment: Great that you found a solution, but please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes Shnugo, I wanted to do that.. but here I found answer in 2 replies.. so was thinking it is injustice to other person if I select one.. But still I am doing it as theoretically your answer was more correct..

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is convert month name into month no and sort accordingly.
I tried one method there are  multiple methods for conversion check if it is working or not.

```
Declare @Period char = 'M'
Declare @FinalDateId int = 20170101;

SELECT
    Period, SUM(CAST(TotalAmount AS bIGINT)) AS Value
FROM            
    (SELECT        
         CASE 
            WHEN @Period = 'D' 
               THEN CAST(d.DateName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'W' 
               THEN CAST(d.WeekOfYear AS VARCHAR(50))
            WHEN @Period = 'M' 
               THEN CAST(d.MonthName AS VARCHAR(50)) 
            WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
               THEN CAST(d.CalendarYear AS VARCHAR(50)) 
         END AS Period, 
         Tr.TotalAmount
     FROM 
         Revenue AS Tr 
     INNER JOIN  
         Dates AS d ON Tr.DateId = d.Id
     WHERE        
         (Tr.DateId BETWEEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @Period = 'D' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 30, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'W' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 364, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'M' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 365, 112) 
                        WHEN @Period = 'Y' 
                           THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char(8), @FinalDateId)) - 3652, 112) END AND @FinalDateId) 
         ) AS TotalRevenue
GROUP BY 
    Period
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN @Period = 'M' 
          THEN DATEPART(MM,convert(datetime,Period +'01 2017',110))
   END

output:-

Period     Value
January     12500
February    4000
March       2300
April       4750
May         8560
June        4400
July        4550
August      4750
September   5960
October     7350
November    5250
December    187250
```

Comment: same problem in this query as well CONVERT(month, Period) does not work..  I have added script to create table and insert the data as well for verification..

Comment: You are building a date using the existing name and combine it with a date's fragment like `'January ' + '01 2017'` just to cast it to a typed date? This will fail in different culture settings... Btw: The `2017` would have to come in dynamically too, wouldn't it?